# byte[] to string destroying the integers

Tags: c#, packet

I created small not finishd Packet Builder class.
`AddString()` working without problems, but if i use `AddInt()` the console output looks very weird. Any can tell me why the integer not display correctly?

**Main**

```
Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet.builder.AddString(Constants.Requests.GET_RESOURCES);
        packet.builder.AddString("Another_String");
        packet.builder.AddInt(500);

        byte[] byteArray = packet.builder.GetByteBuffer();
        Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(byteArray));
```

> ByteArray Output: Get_Resources:Another_String:?☺:
>
> 47-65-74-5F-52-65-73-6F-75-72-63-65-73-00-3A-41-6E-6F-74-68-65-72-5F-53-74-72-69-6E-67-00-3A-F4-01-00-00-00-3A

As you can see: ?☺ is definitly wrong. The functions are almost the same.

**Class**

```
class Packet
    {
        public Builder builder;

        public Packet()
        {
            builder = new Builder();
        }

        private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arr)
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            return enc.GetString(arr);
        }

        public static string[] Read(byte[] _recievedData)
        {
            string data = ByteArrayToString(_recievedData).Trim();
            string[] result = data.Split(':');

            return result;
        }


        public class Builder
        {

            private byte[] buffer;
            private int offset;

            //Makes very easy on client to filter packets...
            private byte[] seperator;

            public Builder()
            {
                offset = 0;
                buffer = new byte[4096];
                seperator = BitConverter.GetBytes(':');
            }


            public void AddInt(int intValue)
            {
                byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
                
                for (int x = 0; x < byteArray.Length; x++)
                {
                    buffer[x + offset] = byteArray[x];
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < seperator.Length; y++)
                {
                    buffer[byteArray.Length + (y + 1) + offset] = seperator[y];
                }

                offset += (byteArray.Length + seperator.Length);
            }

            public void AddString(string str)
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

                for (int x = 0; x < byteArray.Length; x++)
                {
                    buffer[x + offset] = byteArray[x];
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < seperator.Length; y++)
                {
                    buffer[byteArray.Length + (y + 1) + offset] = seperator[y];
                }

                offset += (byteArray.Length + seperator.Length);
            }

            public byte[] GetByteBuffer()
            {
                return buffer;
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                buffer = null;
                offset = 0;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to inspect the contents of the byte array and possibly determine what, if anything, is wrong? At minimum, it would allow you to isolate your problem and ask a more focused question that would not require us to mentally interpret your code.

Comment: Can't you just use `BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue).Reverse().ToArray()` on the `AddInt`?

Comment: Im alredy try to debug it, but cant find the error. Thats why im ask the community. I dont have much experience with bytes. I try @Codexer, thanks.

Comment: You add the internal bytes of the integer, that is not the same as the decimal string representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine. Possibly it is not what you want but following code converts an int in 4 bytes because it is a 32-bit integer.

```
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
```

at the end of your output, you see those 4 bytes as expected in little endian format `F4-01-00-00` because `500` in hexadecimal is `0x01F4`. This explains why you are getting, what you are getting.

Now I am assuming that you are expecting `500` instead of `?☺`. Following code should fetch you desired result:

```
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue.ToString());
```

This will add a string representation of the number instead of binary representation. Based on the return type of `Read` function, the need seems to be a string representation.

Comment: Make sense now. Thank you!